# Database connection aborted

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I created my Database using SQL server 2008 R2.
Then tried to attach it using Visual C# Developer 2010.

It gives me an error. Attached is the screen[image]shot

Thank you
Sun

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem you'll need to upgrade to SQL Server 2008. Express edition is fine, as long as the database is less than 4Gb in size.

Comment: It hardly has any data on it. 3tables with each table 5rows of data. All varchar and int datatypes. Size 3MB